# Undefined symbols when using ODE in C

Tags: c, xcode, macos, linker, ode-library

I'm trying to use [ODE](http://www.ode.org) in my C project on Xcode 4.5.1 (MacOS 10.8). I used

```
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

to install the lib. I then tried to compile a test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ode/ode.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    dWorldID world = dWorldCreate();
    return 0;
}
```

I added `dSINGLE` in Build Settings->Preprocessor Macros and `libode.a` in my Xcode project.

When I try to build and run I get a bunch of errors like

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "std::terminate()", referenced from:
>         _dJointGroupCreate in libode.a(ode.o)
>         _dBodyCreate in libode.a(ode.o)
>         dxJointBall::dxJointBall(dxWorld*) in libode.a(ball.o)
>         dxJointBall::dxJointBall(dxWorld*) in libode.a(ball.o)
>         dxJointFixed::dxJointFixed(dxWorld*) in libode.a(fixed.o)
>         dxJointFixed::dxJointFixed(dxWorld*) in libode.a(fixed.o)
>         dxJointHinge::dxJointHinge(dxWorld*) in libode.a(hinge.o)
>         ...
>       .
>       .
>       .
>       .

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The very same procedure works fine if I create a C++ project instead of a C one.

Did I forget to add something in the build settings in order to make it work?

Comment: perhaps you are forgetting to include some library. Here the linker is complaining. So maybe you should give the appropriate library to the linker.

Comment: @RajTendulkar The only output of the compilation of ODE should be `libode.a`. I don't know if there is something special to do to use the lib in a C program (in C++ the very same procedure works fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved adding

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib
```

to the Xcode project.